# How to check this SSD's TBW?

Tags: ssd

Is there a way to check this SSD TBW?

I have tried HDsentinel, CDInfo, and even Micron Storage Executive.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just realized you might not be asking for the specification of the drive when it comes to total bytes written but want the current value.

Comment: I can't tell if the Micron software is offering a firmware update for your drive or not, however, if that software is not presenting you the value I am not aware of any software that would.  If you are just looking for the specification value, I have that value, but I doubt that is what your looking for.

Comment: I just want to check the current health of it. I have the datasheet/ specifications of this model. Tks.